# SQL Server stored procedure store multiple rows of SELECT statement result into single variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query with a `SELECT` statement that will return 2 or more rows as a result. How can I store these rows of data into a variable? Because I need the variable to check whether any of the rows is empty/null. How can I achieve this?

So far I've done this:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @AINum = ISNULL(so.U_SI7_DPDocNum, 0), @soDocNum = so.DocNum
    FROM  
        DLN1 doline 
    INNER JOIN 
        ORDR so ON doline.BaseRef = so.DocNum
    WHERE 
        doline.DocEntry = @docEntry

    WHILE(@AINum IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        IF(@AINum <= 0)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @errCode = 003;
            RETURN;
        END
    END
END
```

UPDATED query using EXISTS

```
SELECT @errCode = 003
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT so.U_SI7_DPDocNum
                  FROM DLN1 doline 
                  INNER JOIN ORDR so ON doline.BaseRef = so.DocNum
                  WHERE doline.DocEntry = @docEntry)
RETURN;
```

The `@AINum` will have to store multiple rows of data from the SELECT statement result. `@errCode` is an output variable.

Thank you.

Comment: table var, or ..... a table!

Comment: @MitchWheat can the variable inside the table being used in while condition and null checking? Because it gaves me error when I want to use it in the while loop.

Comment: Tsql should not be procedural.  You probably don't need a while loop.  Look at Exists and 'Not Exists'

Comment: @granadaCoder I've updated the question with Exists clause, could you help me take a look on it? Thanks!

Comment: @Squirrel If the query return more than 2 rows and one of the `U_SI7_DPDocNum` is NULL, then pops up the errCode on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- initialize to 0
SELECT  @errCode = 0;

-- assign value of 003 if it the DPDocNum is NULL or < 0
SELECT  @errCode = 003
FROM    DLN1 doline 
INNER JOIN ORDR so ON doline.BaseRef = so.DocNum
WHERE   doline.DocEntry = @docEntry
AND     (so.U_SI7_DPDocNum IS NULL OR so.U_SI7_DPDocNum <= 0)
```